# Get count of entries per period excluding first one (SQL query)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to make SQL query, that would give me count of buyers per month, who made at least one purchase in that month, NOT COUNTING this buyer's first purchase ever.

For example, I have this table:

```
id  bill_date
1   2014-01-14
1   2014-02-14
2   2014-02-14
2   2014-02-18
1   2014-02-19
2   2014-03-14
1   2014-03-14
1   2014-03-16
1   2014-04-08
1   2014-06-03
2   2014-06-10
1   2014-06-11
3   2014-11-07
3   2014-11-13
```

Therefore:

```
Jan - 1 bill for ID1
Feb - 2 bills for ID2, 2 bills for ID1
Mar - 1 bill for ID1, 2 bills for ID2
Apr - 1 bill for ID1
Jun - 2 bills for ID1, 1 bill for ID2
Nov - 2 bills for ID3
```

Expected results:

```
period    accounts
2014-02   2
2014-03   2
2014-04   1
2014-06   2
2014-11   1
```

Basically, since ID1 made a purchase in January, do a distinct count for each month after January that they appear.

Since ID2 made two purchases in February, they would count for 1 in February, and then one every month after that (even if they made multiple purchases).

For ID3 they made two purchases in November, so count them as 1 for November. Had they made one purchase in November, and another in December, December would show one, but November would not show anything.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? MS Sql, Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you :

```
SELECT date_format(t1.bill_date, '%Y-%m') AS dt,
       Count(DISTINCT t1.id)              AS cnt
FROM   tempt t1
       JOIN (SELECT id,
                    Min(bill_date) AS bill_date
             FROM   tempt
             GROUP  BY id) AS t2
         ON t1.id = t2.id
            AND t1.bill_date <> t2.bill_date
GROUP  BY date_format(t1.bill_date, '%Y-%m')
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/184c8/6)

Answer (score 0):

You first need to use LEFT to allow you to group by the first 7 characters (year and date).  Then, get the count of the distinct accounts in that month.  Finally and most importantly, to only count IDs that have purchases in previous months, you have to join back to the table and only count rows in t1 where there is an earlier row for the same account in t2.

```
SELECT LEFT(t1.bill_date, 7) AS period, COUNT(DISTINCT t1.id) AS accounts
FROM tableName t1
JOIN tableName t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
  AND t2.bill_date < t1.bill_date
GROUP BY period
ORDER BY period
```

Fiddle as well:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/184c8/6

(Edit : I removed the "HAVING accounts > 0" clause.  It was unnecessary.)

Answer (score 0):

You want to first get distinct buyers for each month, then do your counting. This is a portable solution and more in line with the way you would process it mentally.

select x.period, count(x.buyer_id) accounts from
(SELECT distinct DATE_FORMAT(bill_date, '%Y-%m') period,  buyer_id
from billing)x
group by x.period

I don't like the idea of the column name "id" so I have named it "buyer_id" here. Consider changing your column name and us id for the primary key instead.